# TF 2.1 installed in conda env. but TF2.3 imported. even TF2.1 env is activated

Tags: python, tensorflow, module, anaconda, environment-variables

Python version is 3.7.7
Anaconda env name is "py37tf21"
env "py37tf21" is installed tensorflow2.1
but, if I import tensorflow, the version is 2.3
what is the problem?

I attached anaconda console image below
[image]

Comment: How did you install tensorflow?

Comment: Your question is difficult to read. Try to write in full sentences and give a bit of context: what is your environment; what have you done to end up in this state.

Comment: I'm not familiar with English...^^ thank you for modifying.

Comment: Please share the terminal output as text, not an image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You installed tensorflow-gpu 2.1 (which is just adds GPU support) but the actual tensorflow is tf-nightly 2.3 (nightly means that it's updated every night).

Try

```
conda uninstall tf-nightly
conda install tensorflow=2.1
```

Comment: Thank you. I didn't know about tf-nightly. now, the problem is solved.